# Differentiation in Several Variables

Tags: analysis, derivatives, manifolds

PROPOSITION:

Let $U \subset R^{d}$, and $V \subset R^{n}$

Consider a function $\alpha: U \rightarrow V$. Assume a($\textbf{0}$)= $\textbf{p}$, and that Da($\textbf{x}$) has rank d for all $\textbf{x} \in U$. Therefore, there exists a matrix $B \in Mat_{n,n-d}$ such that Da($\textbf{0}$)B is non degenerate.

Consider the mapping:
$\beta : U \times R^{n-d} \rightarrow R^{n}$

$(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) \rightarrow \alpha(\textbf{x}) + B\textbf{y} $

### Then $D\beta(\textbf{0})= D\alpha(\textbf{0})B$.

I tried testing this proposition, but my solution isn't working out as shown below:

Let $\alpha: U \rightarrow R^{3}$

where $U= ((u,v): \sqrt{(u-3)^2 + (v-3)^2}<3)$

$\alpha(u,v)= (u,v, (u-3)^2+ (v-3)^2)$

Therefore, $D\alpha(u,v)= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2(u-3)\\
0& 1 & 2(v-3)
\end{pmatrix}$

This matrix has rank 2 for $(u,v) \in U$.

Therefore $B \in Mat_{3,1}$, and $y \in R$

Let $B= \begin{pmatrix}
B_{1}\\
B_{2}\\
B_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$

Therefore $\beta(\textbf{x},y)=  \beta(u,v,y)= \alpha(u,v) + By $

so

$$D\beta(u,v,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0 & 2(u-3)\\
0& 1&  2(v-3)\\
0& 0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0\\
B_{1}& B_{2}& B_{3}\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Therefore, $D\alpha(0,0)B = \begin{pmatrix}
B_{1}- 6B_{3}\\
B_{2}- 6B_{3}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

But $D\beta(0,0)= \begin{pmatrix}
1& 0 &-6\\
0& 1& -6\\
B_{1}& B_{2} & B_{3}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: What are the dimensions of $U$ and $V$? Are they subsets of Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^k$, or something more general?

Comment: The dimension of U and V are given as : $U \subset R^{d}$ and $V \subset R^{n}$

Comment: If $D\beta(\mathbf{0})$ and $D\alpha(\mathbf{0})\, B$ have different dimensions, how can you expect them to be equal? The types of things need to make sense before worrying at all about the possible values.